# CSS HTML - How to add more outer colour on the drop down menus and more than one word per drop down

Tags: html, css

[image]

**CODE**

```css
div.box {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 5
}



#navMenu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

#navMenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 30px;
}

#navMenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 background:#999;
}

#navMenu ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration:none;
 height: 30px
 width:300px;
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
border:1px solid #000;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#navMenu ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
 bottom: 31px

}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}

/*****************************************************************************/

#navMenu li:hover {
 background:#09F;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background:#CCC;
 color: #000;
}

#navMenu a:hover {
 color: #000;
}

.clearFloat {
 clear:both;
 margin: 0'
 padding:0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ZEFROLITY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
   <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
 <img src="icon1.png" alt="zefrolity" width="50%" height="50%">
 </div>


 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="navMenu">

 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

 <br class="clearFloat">

 </div> <!--end navMenu -->
 </div> <!--end wrapper div -->





</body>
</html>
```

I want the drop down menus to cover the whole bottom not just some of the left and I want more grey colour next to the letters so more than one word can go on the same line and it looks more clean

Kind Regards

Zefrolity thanks in advance

Comment: On a first notice, you're using a percentage value for the width and height of the icon1 image, which are not valid attribute values. If you want to use a percentage value, use it as a style and not as an tag attribute value.



For instance you can use:
`<img src="icon1.png" alt="zefrolity" width="50" height="50">`
OR
`<img src="icon1.png" alt="zefrolity" style="width:50%; height:50%">`
But not:
`<img src="icon1.png" alt="zefrolity" width="50%" height="50%">`

Comment: Also, your navigation list doesn't have a fixed position since you placed it directly below the image code without applying a style that would fix it at the bottom of the page. In other words, if you remove the image, the nav bar will be positioned on top of the page.

Can you include a link your image so that I can work with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you missed a semi-colon after one of your CSS rules (`height: 30px`), so the rest of the rules for that selector weren't being called.

So solve your problem (as I understand it), you need to give the first level li's a percentage width.  There's 8 items so to make the menu cover the whole width, it's 100/8 (12.5%).  I've added a direct child selector to add styles specifically for this first level `li`.  E.g. `#navMenu > ul > li` will pick up only the first level `li`, not the child one. I made a few other comments through the code as direction.

```css
div.box {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 5
}



#navMenu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

#navMenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 30px;
}

#navMenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 background:#999;
}

/* Direct child selector for first level li only */
#navMenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%; /* Set width here (100 / 8 items) */
}

#navMenu ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration:none;
 height: 30px; /* Was missing semi-colon */
 /* width:300px; Remove, will take up width of parent */
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#navMenu ul ul {
 position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* Be full width of parent */
 visibility: hidden;
 bottom: 100%; /* Be 100% from bottom of parent */

}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}

/*****************************************************************************/

#navMenu li:hover {
 background:#09F;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background:#CCC;
 color: #000;
}

#navMenu a:hover {
 color: #000;
}

.clearFloat {
 clear:both;
 margin: 0'
 padding:0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ZEFROLITY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
   <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
 <img src="icon1.png" alt="zefrolity" width="50%" height="50%">
 </div>


 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="navMenu">

 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

 <br class="clearFloat">

 </div> <!--end navMenu -->
 </div> <!--end wrapper div -->





</body>
</html>
```